# How to make an index static for a python lambda expression

Tags: python, indexing, lambda

Say I have these lines of code

```
index = 1
test = lambda t : t[index]+1
index = 0
print(test([5, 0]))
```

The result is 6, I would expect the result to be 1. How can I make the index inside the lambda expression static without writing `t[1]+1`, i.e. using a variable?

Comment: `argument = [5, 0]`, `index = 0`, `argument[index] = 5`, `5 + 1 = 6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's closures are *late binding*. This means that the values of variables used in closures are looked up at the time the function is called.

To avoid the late binding effect you can use a lambda with a default arg:

```
index = 1
test = lambda t, index=index: t[index]+1  # binds index at definition time
index = 0
print(test([5, 0]))  # 1
```

Comment: shouldn't it be e.g. `test = lambda t, _index=index: t[_index]+1`

Comment: No, it will work either way. The two names belong to different namespaces.

Comment: @rst I prefixed the parameter name with an underscore to make clear it was not part of the function's API (python convention: names starting with a leading underscore are "private" (implementation details) and should not be used by client code) - technically the parameter name is totally irrelevant, it would work the same with "spam", "dead_parrot" or whatever.

Comment: @EugeneYarmash, Is there a way to write your solution without `lambda`? I ask because this is just plain ugly. I mean, I'd feel bad if I wrote this kind of code for others to decipher.

Comment: @jpp: you can use a `def` as well. This is exactly equivalent to the above lambda: `def test(t, index=index): return t[index] + 1`

Comment: @EugeneYarmash, Got it, would be much clearer in my opinion as: `def test(t, idx=index): return t[idx] + 1`. Using variable name same as argument is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

`index` is neither an argument nor a local variable in `test()` so it is indeed resolved as a a nonlocal (+> it's looked up in the enclosing scopes).

The simple solution is to make `index` an argument of `test` with a default value capturing the value of `index` at definition time:

```
index = 1
test = lambda t, _index=index: t[_index]+1
index = 0
print(test([5, 0]))
```

Comment: I accepted Eugene Yarmash's solution although yours is basically identical. His explanation is just slightly more comprehensible. I hope your not mad

Comment: Nope, why ? FWIW, we posted approximately at the same time and I wouldn't even have posted mine if I had seen his before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `lambda` to return a `lambda`:

```
test = (lambda index: lambda t: t[index] + 1)(index)
```

This way the `index` variable is local to the returned lambda function.

Comment: Are you competing for the Rube Goldberg award ?-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator.itemgetter` to create a callable object which extracts the *n*th item from a list:

```
from operator import itemgetter

index = 1
get_val = itemgetter(index)
test = lambda t: get_val(t) +1
index = 0

print(test([5, 0]))  # 1
```

But there's no reason here for a `lambda` statement, you can define a function explicitly:

```
def test(t):
    return get_val(t) + 1
```